# Getting unexpected token error '<' in console while running react

Tags: reactjs

> getting unexpected token error while running react code

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <h2>Add React in One Minute</h2>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script>
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
    root.render(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>);
    </script>
       
  </body>
 </html>
```

[React official website][1]

I am trying to run react code from the official react website but getting unexpected token error,

Comment: JSX is not valid JavaScript, so it needs to be converted to valid JS. You can use a tool like [`babel`](https://babeljs.io/) to convert it to valid code.

Comment: I never used babel so how do i go about?

Comment: Did you use the create-react-app, or is this just in a plain html file?

Comment: Converted using babel and it worked--

"use strict";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render( /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello, world!"));

Comment: i used just plain html file

Comment: You can (for now) you can just use Babel standalone: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone

Answer (score 1):

You need Babel to use JSX. Just add this tag to your page:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Now you can use JSX in any  tag by adding `type="text/babel"` attribute to it.

This approach is fine for learning and creating simple demos. However, it makes your website slow and isn’t suitable for production. For production you should install Babel using NPM:

Go to your project folder in the terminal, and paste these two commands:

Step 1: Run `npm init -y`

Step 2: Run `npm install babel-cli@6 babel-preset-react-app@3`

The only requirement is to have **Node.js** installed on your computer.

Comment: This also required: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#run-jsx-preprocessor else error messages will occur